# Why might \SI (siunitx) and \ref work in TeXShop, but not the more updated \qty (siunitx) and \eqref?

Tags: siunitx, texshop

I am trying to convert a document which runs perfectly in Overleaf to a local file which I can edit and compile in TeXShop but I am running into undefined control sequences, and cannot even get a completely minimal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\qty{5}{\cm}
\end{document}
```

to work.

Comment: For starters, you haven't even defined a document class ...

Comment: @Ingmar Just a typo with the code highlighting. (It swallows whatever is in the same line as the three backticks.)

Comment: The command `\qty` and friends are new in version 3 of `siunitx` that was released in May 2021 (I think). This means that the new commands are only available if your TeX installation is reasonably new. New Overleaf documents run a TeX live 2021, where `siunitx` is available in v3. But on your local installation you may have an older TeX live with an older `siunitx`. You can find out your exact package version by inspecting the `.log` file.

Comment: Just to make it clear: `\ref` and `\eqref` have nothing to do with `siunitx`. `\ref` is defined in the LaTeX format (and has been defined there for years - I'm assuming since the start) and is therefore always available when you use LaTeX. `\eqref` is defined in `amsmath` (and again is not a new command; but you need `\usepackage{amsmath}` or another `\usepackage` that causes `amsmath` to be loaded like `\usepackage{mathtools}`, this is the same on Overleaf and locally).

Comment: texshop is just the editor you are using to write the file it isn't directly related to any tex error, presumably your local texshop is using an older latex installation that does not have the latest siunitx. so you just need to update your tex system.